# How to correct siding on a porch

Tags: siding, vapor-barrier

A piece of siding on my enclosed front porch blew away in a recent storm. It made me realize 1) that there's insulation directly under the siding which seems, weird?? Is that normal? shouldn't there be some house wrap or something? And 2) that the way the siding is attached, allows water to run behind it. The top channel piece has nothing above it to prevent water from getting in behind it.

As a band-aid fix I can easily get a piece of matching siding and reinstall it the same way. However, I'm interested in learning what the better longer term solution would be. My thought is that somehow the siding needs to fit under the casing for the windows, is this correct? What part names should I be looking for something that would do this? Additionally, should there be some sort of vapor barrier/tyvek situation between the siding and the foam? The porch is unheated and doesn't have floor insulation so it's generally the same temperature as outside.

[image: Missing siding]
[image: Missing siding attachement]

Comment: Insulation board is commonly used under vinyl siding when applied over an existing siding. It flattens out the surface and since this type of siding cannot be nailed tightly to the siding, it won't allow the thin foam layer, usually only about a 1/4" thick, to conform to the surface where the lap of the original may not coincide with the new siding the way it would otherwise need.

Comment: Oh that's good to know, thanks!